# Repairing Leak in Refrigerant Lines

Tags: hvac, leak, central-air

We recently found and pinpointed a leak in my copper refrigerant line (the non-insulated line) and was wondering if there was anyway to repair and replace that one spot on the line (like if there were a water leak)? The spot is outside and accessible.  Do they sell repair kits for something like this? I just want to know before I spend almost 1500 to get the entire lines replaced all together.

Answer (score 1):

An HVAC technician should be able to repair the line, assuming the rest of the line is in good shape. Refrigerant line repair is not a diy project, as it requires specialized tools and training, as well as a license in most places.

After the leak is repaired, you'll have to recharge the system. Which also is not a project for a typical diyer.

Comment: Will they want to replace the entire line or just the section where the leak is?

Comment: @mjt117 it depends on the condition of the line, and the extent of the damage. Whoever comes, let them look at it. Then have them explain how they plan to fix it, and what it will cost. If you think they're doing more than is required, ask them to explain why they have to do what they plan. Remember, they work for you, and there's likely loads of competition. If you don't feel comfortable with their plan, tell them you'd like to get a second opinion. Then have another company come take a look.